# Prioritizing Urgent Telegram Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications

I'm trying to find a way to set the highest priority for specific Telegram notifications on my iPhone.
The reason behind this is that there are certain notifications on particular channels that require swift actions, and I receive a multitude of notifications from various applications. I would like these crucial notifications from specific Telegram groups to stand out amidst the others.

Additionally, I'm interested in solutions that make use of Shortcuts on iOS.

I've already explored notification settings in both the Telegram app itself and iOS system settings, but there doesn't seem to be a direct option to assign a particular priority to certain notifications.

I'm wondering if anyone has found a solution or workaround to ensure that some Telegram notifications are more prominent or urgent than others, especially those from specific groups.

Comment: Would love to see Android's notification channels finally make it to iOS one day 